# Render theme in mapsforge

Tags: android, user-interface, mapsforge

I use mapsforge in my app. I want to use different theme for create different font size. I create different them and save in asset folder and i change my theme with below code but the program cnanot load true theme! I want when click on A button, load xhdpi but when click on this, load a theme with vry small font!

```
File f=new File(destination,"xhdpi");
mapView.stRenderTheme(f);
```

in xhdpi theme, i set big font(30) but when i run this code theme change to small font and i dont know, the program of where load this theme! :D

and in the last, i think, mapsforge or my app use a default theme for changing theme but im not sure and i dont know where is the problem!

Thanks for advise and your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mapView.setTextScale(3); // default scale size is 1
```

if it works as works for me , you can give scaling as an option to user!